# How to drag a <p> and drop over the <img> tag in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I want to drag my image and drop in the `<div>` which is working. After my image is dropped i want to drag the text in the `<p>` tag and drop on the image and the result should be like the image as backgound and the text infront of the image. And later the text `<p>` should be draggable again to change the position from left side of the `<div>` to right or whatever.

My problem is when i add style with z-index for `<p>` tag the `<p>` tag is unable to drag. If the style is removed then the text goes behind the image when both image and text are dropped in the `<div>`. I just want to drop the text comes infront of the `<img>`. 
Also please help me to find a solution to drag again to change the position of the text which is dropped once.
My code is

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML>
    <html>
        <head>
            <style>
                #div1 {
                    width: 400px;
                    height: 240px;
                    padding: 10px;
                    border: 1px solid #aaaaaa;
                }
                img {
                    width: 400px;
                    height: 240px;
                }
            </style>
            <script>
                function allowDrop(ev) {
                    ev.preventDefault();
                }

                function drag(ev) {
                    ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);
                }

                function drop(ev) {
                    ev.preventDefault();
                    var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
                    ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
                }
            </script>
        </head>
        <body>

            <div id="div1" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
            <br>
            <img id="drag1" src="http://sblim.org/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/blank-visiting-card-background-design-p-on-astonishing-free-business-regarding-business-card-background-designs-png.png" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" width="336" height="69" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
            <p id="drag2" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" style="z-index: -1; position:relative;">Hai<p>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: What prevents you to implement what you wish? Please explain your actual problem.

Comment: Please find the updated question

Comment: dont use inline style with drag and drop, try to reduce every not necessary attribute of your markup :)

Comment: @episch I tried with adding the external css also but unable to drag when the position:relative is given. Should i change this style to some other to get this worked?

Comment: make an outline on every element from your markup to check you body sizes, maybe an element isnt display: block :) So you dosnt have enought space to click on that element